# Tutorial for Test complete tool and VB scripts

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, testcomplete

I had just started working on some automated testing tools, namely test complete, which I would be using along with test partner. So I had also started learning VB scripts for this.

I just want to know if anyone could provide me a link so that I could learn this tool, as well as VB scripting more effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6(VS.85).aspx)
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Vbscript/default.asp)
[devguru](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/vbscript/quickref/vbscript_list.html)
[Windows Scripting Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a74hyyw0(VS.85).aspx)
The Test Complete Help can sometimes be helpful, but not usually.

Comment: Tester,Thanks a lot .devguru is pretty very much usefull

Answer (score 1):

Test complete itself has keywords for VB. You can use them or you can define your own keywords by giving it keywords.

It has a tool like object spy with which you can spy on objects properties and make your own repository, through which your automation can easily be done.

Answer (score 0):

When I was using Test Complete a few years ago, we mainly programmed in 'C# script' really was very much JavaScript like, but they had lots of examples on the [AutomatedQA website](http://www.automatedqa.com/support/tutorials/).

That and we recorded scripts of us clicking on things then looked at what that generated.

The third thing we did a lot use their UI inspector widget, to find what was the name of UI components, and there properties.